# Best high/low canny threshold to find Arbitrary number of pixel

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to use canny edge detection in my steganography algorithm so when I need for example 250 pixel for hide info I must find best low/high threshold for canny to find at least 250 sharpest pixel in image.

For another example when I need 500 pixel for hide info I must find low/high threshold to find at least 500 pixel in image.

I thought that I could use a binary search، but it doesn't return optimal threshold.this is my binary search function:

```
function [ th ] = getThreshold( I, N, w )
 % limit is set to 1% of the message
 % length
 % no. of edge pixels,ne ? N + 0.01 × N
 % and ne ? N
 % ne = number of edge pixels in I, when
 % Canny edge detector is used on I with
 % high threshold th and low threshold
 % tl = 0.4 ? th and width w

 limit = (0.01 * N);

 tmax = 0.8;
 tmin = 0;
 set = true;

 while(set)
   th = double((tmax + tmin)/2);
   BW = edge(I,'canny',[tmin tmax],'both',w);
   % it returns the number of pixels in the edges obtained through  Canny
   %     edge detector
   ne = getEdgePixelCount(BW);

   diff = ne - N;
   if diff > limit
      tmin = th;
   elseif diff < 0
      tmax = th;
   else
      set = false;
 end  
end
```

Comment: What about computing sobel magnitude, and keep the N highest?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the optimized threshold as applied by MATLAB itself? From the MATLAB Documentation you have:

> > In all cases, edge chooses the default threshold heuristically, depending on the input data. The best way to vary the threshold is to run edge once, capturing the calculated threshold as the second output argument. Then, starting from the value calculated by edge, adjust the threshold higher (fewer edge pixels) or lower (more edge pixels).>>

So, in order to get the MATLAB optimized threshold for canny you can use

```
   [~, th] = edge(yourpicture,'canny');
```

and then apply the optimized threshold th multiplied by some factor f (from my experience f should be between 1-3), you have to try out:

edgepict=edge(yourpicture,'canny',f*th,'both', sigma);

Note that th is acually a vector containing th_low and th_high. Th_low is by default 0.4*th_high (if I remember correctly), and I would not change that. In addition to the factor f you can also play with the sigma which is by default sqrt(2). Sigma refers to the radius of the gaussian blur applied in the first step of the canny algorithm.